# How to write xpath for close button in the below code?

Tags: firebug

I'm using firebug tool for this :

I tried with "//table[@class='x-btn-medium x-btn-icon-medium-left']/em/button" , But it's not working. Is this the right way ? if wrong, plzz let me know wat's the right one ?

ext-gen251 in this command is dynamic .

```
<button id="ext-gen251" class=" x-btn-text" type="button">Close</button>
```

Below is the code :

```
<div id="ext-comp-1089" class=" x-window" style="position: absolute; z-index: 9003; visibility: visible; left: 500px; top: -39px; width: 600px; display: block;">
        <div class="x-window-tl">
        <div class="x-window-tr">
        <div class="x-window-tc">
        <div id="ext-gen192" class="x-window-header x-unselectable x-window-draggable" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
        <div id="ext-gen198" class="x-tool x-tool-close">&nbsp;</div>
        <span id="ext-gen203" class="x-window-header-text">Details</span>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="ext-gen193" class="x-window-bwrap">
        <div class="x-window-ml">
        <div id="ext-gen196" class="x-window-bl">
        <div class="x-window-br">
        <div class="x-window-bc">
        <div id="ext-gen195" class="x-window-footer x-panel-btns" style="width: 576px;">
        <div id="ext-comp-1090" class="x-panel-fbar x-small-editor x-toolbar-layout-ct" style="width: auto;">
        <table class="x-toolbar-ct" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td class="x-toolbar-left" align="left">
        <td class="x-toolbar-right" align="right">
        <table class="x-toolbar-right-ct" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <table cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
        <tr class="x-toolbar-right-row">
        <td id="ext-gen250" class="x-toolbar-cell">
        <table id="ext-comp-1091" class="x-btn jxCancelBtn x-btn-noicon" cellspacing="0" style="width: 75px;">
        <tbody class="x-btn-medium x-btn-icon-medium-left">
        <tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="x-btn-ml">
        <td class="x-btn-mc">
        <em class="" unselectable="on">
        <button id="ext-gen251" class=" x-btn-text" type="button">Close</button>
        </em>
        </td>
        <td class="x-btn-mr">
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
        <td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div id="ext-gen200" class="x-clear"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close, but it looks like instead of `//table[@class='x-btn-medium x-btn-icon-medium-left']/em/button` you should have `//`**tbody**`[@class='x-btn-medium x-btn-icon-medium-left']//em/button`, since that is where the `class = x-btn-medium x-btn-icon-medium-left` is.

I also changed the end part from `/em/button` to `//em/button`, as there seems to be quite a bit of junk floating around in the html.